# Is it guaranteed that on IValueConverter ConvertBack call other views would update?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, ivalueconverter

Is it guaranteed that on IValueConverter ConvertBack call other views would update and how to enforce it?

I have 4 parameters in a List. Each pair of them can be calculated from another two in a manner like:

```
A = f(a,b)
B = f2(a,b)
a = f3(A,B)
b = f4(A,B)
```

I have them all rendered in one in a ItemsControl. I created a IValueConverter that  can Convert and ConvertBack on demand. During Conversion Back of one item values for other three are updated in the source List.
 I wonder if it is guaranteed that after one List Item ConvertBack call others would be invoked?

Comment: `ConvertBack` never called views to update it only converts target value to source which then is passed to bound property and if that property raises `INPC.PropertyChanged` event it should be picked up by other bound views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not guaranteed. `IValueConverter` does only convert the value which should be set on the model.

For the view to update based on that change, your model should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and raise the [`PropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event after a property was set.

Here is an example of a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string property;
    public string Property 
    { 
        get { return property; }
        set
        {
            property = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Property)));
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that you'd normally use a base class that implements that interface (provided by all MVVM libraries and frameworks).