# How to call Button_click event from Viewmodel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

In my project I used one button "Refresh" to refresh the `DataGrid` and registrtion from. This means when I insert a specific record that time it will insert into a database, and on the UI the Datagrid is not refreshing and the registration form is also maintaining filled information. Then if I click on the "refresh" button then the Datagrid and Registration form will also be refreshed. The problem is I am unable to write the refresh code in my Viewmodel. Therefore I wrote it in my Xaml.cs file. Here is my button click event:

**Xaml.cs**

```
 public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     viewmodelObj = new AndazPatrakViewModel();
     viewmodelObj.BtnKharchKhVisibility = "Collapsed";
     viewmodelObj.BtnUtpannakhVisibility = "Visible";

     viewmodelObj.GetMaxId();
     this.DataContext = viewmodelObj;
 }
```

So in Viewmodel after `Dbcontext.SaveChanges();` I want to call the `Button_Click` event shown above, but it asks for parameters for that function. How can i call this `Button_Click` event from my viewModel?

Comment: Put the code that is in the Button_Click in the ViewModel. And call it from the Button_click (or remove the button_click and assign a command to the button) This way you can call the method from with your viewmodel.

Comment: if i set Command for button .. then required output is not getting..

Comment: Add properties for the 'parameters' to the viewmodel and bind the view to these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already figured out how to get a reference to the code behind class.
So, since your `Button_Click` does not use its parameters, you could call it with `null`.

So, in your viewmodel:

```
codeBehindInstance.Button_Click(null, null);
```

Comment: thank you @Domysee now it works... but my window is not refreshing.. can you tell me how can i do that..??

Comment: @RahulChaudhari you should have a look at `INotifyPropertyChanged` and implement it in your viewmodel. For collections, use `ObservableCollection`. If you did both, it will allow you to write the refresh code in your viewmodel. I answered a question just yesterday with a base implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35807059/3107430).

Comment: @RahulChaudhari why it doesnt work as it is now I'm not sure, I'd have to take a deeper look into your code.

Comment: Yes i used it.. I bind Itemsource one Observablecollection for my datagrid.
and used INotifyPropertyChanged for same observablecollection

Comment: @RahulChaudhari if you like, you can ask a new question why the view doesnt update if you use INotifyPropertyChanged in your viewmodel. Its out of scope for this question, and the answer would probably be too long for a comment.